# How do i sum aliases in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql issue summing the two columns so i can sort the table.

```
SELECT distinct mycall, sm, mm, SUM(IF(sm != '', 1,0)) AS 'a_lake',
       SUM(IF(mm != '', 1,0)) AS 'w_lake' 
FROM ss_log 
WHERE conf = '1' 
GROUP BY `mycall` 
ORDER BY `ss_log`.`mycall` DESC
```

This sql works fine and gives me 'mycall', 'a_lake' and 'w_lake' But I need output to be sorted on ('a_lake'+ 'w_lake') which is total score.

Tried alias and subquery but does not work or gives just 1 row as answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a subquery and access the alias column in outer query. See answer by @Sandesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query..

```
SELECT distinct mycall, sm, mm, SUM(IF(sm != '', 1,0)) + SUM(IF(mm != '', 1,0)) AS 'sum' 
FROM ss_log 
WHERE conf = '1' 
GROUP BY `mycall` 
ORDER BY `ss_log`.`mycall` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ORDER BY a_lake + w_lake DESC, `ss_log`.`mycall` DESC
```

Comment: Yeah but this would become a incompatible query with any other flavor of RDBMS  since not all RDBMS does provide such extension like MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
SELECT
*,
a_lake+w_lake AS TotalScore
FROM
(
SELECT distinct mycall, sm, mm, SUM(IF(sm != '', 1,0)) AS 'a_lake', SUM(IF(mm != '', 1,0)) AS 'w_lake' FROM ss_log WHERE conf = '1' GROUP BY mycall 
) AS A
ORDER BY a_lake+w_lake DESC
```